# Redshift varchar too narrow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, varchar

I've got a table that I populate with tab-separated data from files whose encoding doesn't seem to be utf-8 exactly, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
    url varchar(2000),
    ...
);

COPY tab
FROM 's3://input.tsv'
```

After the copy has completed I run

```
SELECT
MAX(LEN(url))
FROM tab
```

which returns `1525`. I figure, since I'm wasting space I might as well resize the column by almost a quarter by using `varchar(2000)` instead of `varchar(1525)`. But neither redoing the `COPY` nor setting up a new table and inserting the already imported data works. In both cases I get

```
error:  Value too long for character type
```

Why won't the column hold these values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file might be in a multi-byte format.

From the [LEN Function documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LEN.html):

> The LEN function returns an integer indicating the number of characters in the input string. **The LEN function returns the actual number of characters in multi-byte strings, not the number of bytes.** For example, a VARCHAR(12) column is required to store three four-byte Chinese characters. The LEN function will return 3 for that same string.

The extra size of a VARCHAR will not waste disk space due to the compression methods used by Amazon Redshift, but it will waste in-memory buffer space when a block is read from disk and decompressed into memory.

Comment: for reference for others, use the `OCTET_LENGTH` to determine the length of destination field
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_OCTET_LENGTH.html